# Alternative to Data Relationship for updating a new user attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud

Our users all have an existing "College" attribute but I want to add an attribute for "College Code" so that user Jane Doe with American University as her College will now have the attribute 7702 associated with her (because 7702 is the school code for American University).

Documentation is pointing me to Data Relationships, but I understand those can only be used with data extensions, whereas I want to be able to use this attribute with email sends from lists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is a new list attribute not a possibility?

Comment: For the type of thing you're building it sounds like data extensions would be a good tool to implement. How do you intend to enter the "College Code" to a record for a user? Would they enter that? Are you working from an address list that includes that information? Forgive that I work with data extensions and not send lists, is it not possible to add a data column to a send list? Rather easy to add any columns you want to a data extension.

Comment: Is the relationship between users and College/College Code a 1:1 or 1:Many relationship?  Based on your example, it sounds like 1:1 so adding a new profile attribute sounds like it would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do here is add to the subscriber the attribute `College Code`.  You can then update the users via import.  No need to complicate matters with anything more than this.

Even with a 1:Many relationship, you can easily use a delimited string to parse if need be.